# Xcode shows "unidentified developer" alert at each app launch

Tags: xcode

Since I updated to Xcode 15 I get an annoying "app comes unidentified developer, do you confirm you want to open" alert (note: approximate translation).

I can still open and debug my app by clicking the "open" button, but that's a pain.

I have the "sign to run locally" build setting. And I run the debug target.

Any way to solve this or is it just a new Xcode bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same annoying prompt when I upgraded to macOS 14.0 and I'm using Xcode 15.0

The following link had the answer for me : https://forums.kodeco.com/t/macos-sonoma-xcode-15/190495

There were 2 steps mentioned in the link, the 3rd step below automatically happened for me when I did the 2nd, but its probably the only thing you actually need to change:

1. Link your Apple ID using Xcode > Settings > Accounts
2. Set the Team to the newly linked account in Signings & Capabilities. I'm not too familiar with Xcode, but I found this by selecting the root of the project in the project navigator, then selected the TARGET, then selecting the Signings & Capabilities tab. Simply picked me in the Team dropdown.
3. Also make sure that 'Signing Certificate' in the macOS section of the 'Signings & Capabilities' tab is not set to 'Sign to Run Locally'. Mine is set to 'Development'.

I did get the warning once more, but haven't had it for a while now, so hopefully it works.

Comment: Didn't work.
In addition, my apple Id was already correctly linked.
The problem only appears once when you make a new build. So the fact that it worked the second is not a proof if you didn't change something in between the runs.

Comment: Shame it didn't work for you. I'm happily changing lots of stuff between builds and no longer get the prompt. If I reset the Team back to None, then the prompt reappears when I do a new build. I noticed setting the team also automatically changed the 'Signing Certificate' value to 'Development'. If I change that back to 'Sign to Run Locally' then I start getting the prompt again even with the Team set. So, it mIght be worth checking what you've got in 'Signing Certificate'.

Comment: Changing from "SIgn to run Locally" to "Development" made the trick ! If you update your answer with that, I'll acccept it :-)

Comment: Good to know that worked. I've updated the answer.

Comment: If this does not work, try cleaning the project. It's probably due to a previous version in the build folder

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not a solution when signing to run locally is the intended option for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this. I changed the Bundle Identifier by removing a "-" from the name and then built it again. The error then disappeared. I then added the "-" back and it still built!

Comment: Didn't work (I indeed had a '-' in the bundle identifier).
The problem only appears once when you make a new build. So the fact that it worked the second is not a proof if you didn't change something in between the runs.